# Exclude column A Table 1 where column B in Table 2

Tags: join, filter, exists

I am trying to query where we exclude rows from Table 1 where column B that includes column A and column B is in Table 2. Example:
Table 1
Department |   Employee |column3,4,5 etc...

1          |    Tom     |  a,b,c
2          |    Brian   |  a,b,c
1          |    SAM     |  a,b,c

Table2

Supervisor |   Subordinate  | column3,4,5etc...

Tom        |     Larry      | x,y,z

Eric       |     Jim        | x,y,z

Sally      |     Mary       | x,y,z

In my query I want to exclude any row in table 1 where department is 1 since at least 1 row in table 1 where department is 1 has an employee in table 2 either supervisor or subordinate. I do not want anything associated with table 2 in my results. In my example even though Sam is not in Table2 I want to exclude that row since Department 1 already has another row with an employee that is in Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.department
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT t2.department
   FROM table1
   JOIN table2 ON employee = supervisor
   OR employee = subordinate) mt2 ON t1.department = t2.department
WHERE m2.department IS NULL
```